# How to map rows from a database into a list of objects?

Tags: c#, dapper, filehelpers

Below is the example class of the object and .txt file, I use filehelpers to create this class,then I read a .txt file using FileHelpers and it converts this file into these objects and I put them in a List.

.txt file:

```
1122233
4455566
```

Example class:

```
[FixedLengthRecord(FixedMode.AllowLessChars)]
public class Example
{

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    public string first;

    [FieldFixedLength(3)]
    public string second;

    [FieldFixedLength(2)]
    public string third;
}
```

Reading this with filehelpers gives me 2 objects of Example.The first Example.first value being '11' etc.
I push this data in a database with by converting the List to a DataTable and using SqlBulkCopy. This all goes well.

The table in the database just contains 3 columns(varchar) with column names; first,second and third.

The problem comes when I try to fetch the data back from the database and map it back into a List, I use the following code (using Dapper) for this:

```
IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var rows = connection.Query<Example>("select * from examplesTable");
        foreach (Example e in rows)
        {
            examples.Add(e);    //List<Example> examples
        }
```

This returns the correct amount of rows, however if I try to fetch data from the objects, it contains null data. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: "however if I try to fetch data from the objects" - which part of the code does this refer to?

Comment: @Hughnited I tested this with adding MessageBox.Show(e.First); to the foreach loop but it show nothing(empty window). I also tried converting that List to a DataTable and pushing it back to the database, the result is that it pushes the correct amount of rows but the data is all null.

Comment: In the foreach: examples.Add(e); MessageBox.Show(e.First); //returns blank window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check that you have the data loaded correctly before the SQL bulk insert and then that you are not getting any errors from the bulk insert.

Does the table in SQL Management studio have the correct data?

If you have the correct data trying just reading as a data table to see what is brought back as that will be object values rather than a specific type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes the data is loaded correctly. I tried your tip by reading it as a DataTable, and it worked! It shows all the correct data. But I need a List of objects of the data, so I tried converting that datatable to a list and again, it shows all nulls.. :(

Comment: I fixed it, my conversion to list was bad. Thanks for the idea to read it as a DataTable!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to just write `foreach (Example e in rows)`, you should create constructor for Example, that will create an object of Example based on the data from each row. It would look kinda like

```
foreach (DaraRow r in rows)
        {
            Example e = new Examaple(r["First"],r["Second"]);
            examples.Add(e);    //List<Example> examples
        }
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this.